# mysql unique index on char column not getting used with IN clause

Tags: mysql, django

Mysql version - 5.7.22

Table definition

```
CREATE TABLE `books` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uuid` char(32) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(254) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `book_uuid` (`uuid`),
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=115 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT `books`.`id`,
                `books`.`uuid`,
                `books`.`title`
FROM `books`
WHERE (`books`.`uuid` IN ("334222a0e99b4a3e97f577665055208e",
                            "979c059840964934816280ba85c67221",
                            "4e2978c765dd435998666ea3083666e5",
                            "535aa78ba80e4215bbf75fb1e20cc5f3",
                            "f969fb10c72b4875aabdf75c1b493524",
                            "1daa0015055444a4b1c0821618a7a4d9",
                            "04f34ede284a4b86b0adddb405d30a75",
                            "513cad12c88c44c6ab248d43643459b9",
                            "de2bde6d016f4381ad0ba714234386fa",
                            "f645c2c9f1594a199a960b97b7015986",
                            "3ce02c072f24447a8a7b269a19ec554f",
                            "75450daf9d024d9d9c0df038437ae2c2",
                            "0e822042b50b4f79bb38304e0acde6f0",
                            "38d808fb3f9a4f57b4f7b30a141e7169",
                            "ecd424abd3a94a339383f6f8e668655e"))
ORDER BY `books`.`id` DESC
LIMIT 15;
```

when i do explain on this query it doesn't pick the index

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table           | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | books           | NULL       | ALL  | book_uuid     | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  107 |    12.15 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------------+
```

strangely the index is correctly used when there are 12 or less entries passed to the IN clause (without forcing index)

forcing the index works, but I cannot force index as this query is created by django ORM, cannot use django-mysql 's [force_index](https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/queryset_extensions.html#django_mysql.models.force_index) as I am on Innodb

***Note***: I know 'distinct' and 'limit' can be avoided in this query, but its part of a bigger query, so i have kept it as is

Comment: Do you notice a difference in execution time when there are more than 12 entries? It could be that MySQL has determined that there is no need to use the index because of the number of rows

Comment: I see the execution time is same with and without using index

Comment: So then MySQL is correctly identifying that the index is not required for the query